# Implementing security in Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework

At my client site the database user has permissions to execute stored procedures only.

Database user doesn’t have permissions to execute queries directly.

But I have used Entity Framework, and no stored procedures used.

What can I do?

Answer (score 1):

In such scenario it is better to use native SQL + ADO.NET directly. The main power of EF is in mapping, linq / ESQL querying and loading strategies. Once you are limited to stored procedures you will lose support for latter two = no querying and no loading strategies. You will still have support for mapping but it will come with performance costs and it will demand strict limitations on your stored procedures.

Answer (score 0):

The Entity Framework allows you to map each entity to a set of stored procedures that will execute the insert, delete and update.

That way the user won't have to execute queries directly when modifying the data in your database.

If the user also doesn't have Select permissions, you need stored procedures to access the data. The Entity Framework can help you because you can import Stored Procedures in the SSDL part of your EDMX and then you can map those stored procedures to functions on your ObjectContext.

Comment: How can we do this?any use full links?